# general mathematical description of Pow algorithms

Tags: proof-of-work, ethash

Is it possible to consider a chain of blocks as an acyclic graph,
where to add the next block (or node, if we are thinking about the blockchain as a graph), it is necessary to solve a computationally difficult problem, such as:

Find `x`, such that:

`H(x) ≤ y`, where `y` is a dynamically calculated target.

For Bitcoin, there seems to be such a formula that is suitable:

`SHA256(SHA256(Н(block contents || nonce)) < targethash`,

with various values of ​​`nonce` chosen until one is found that satisfies the above condition.

For Ethereum, from the yellow paper, we have:
[image]

and what about other algorithms of PoW? Can they also be classified under such a description?

Sorry for my English. I hope my question will be clear. It will be great if you correct my mistakes

Comment: what do you mean by other algorithms of POW?  do you mean the other proof of * (stake,..)

Comment: I mean proof of work algorithms, which uses in other cryptocurrencies @Badr Bellaj

Comment: other crypto like ? for every project read its whitepaper

Comment: Litecoin,Namecoin,Feathercoin... @Badr Bellaj

Comment: What are you intending to achieve by classifying blockchains as acyclic graphs? Are you wanting a discussion of the formal model of blockchains in academia as the answer to this question?